# How to handle dependencies of NuGet development-only package?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I'm writing a MSBuild task to convert SVG images to XAML drawings (this will help me use SVG images in my project as-is, without the need to handle SVGs in runtime). There is a [SharpVectors](http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/) library, that perfectly fits to my needs and I'm using it to perform the actual conversion. This library is available as NuGet Package.

Later I'm planning to pack my Task into separate NuGet package to use it in several projects. The problem I faced is that I don't know how to utilize the package dependency mechanism in case of "development-only" packages. In fact, I don't know how to make my assembly with MSBuild task inside to be able to resolve their referenced assemblies, located in the dependencies (SharpVectors in my case).

In the usual build process this problem doesn't exist because all the assemblies from the dependencies are just copied to the output folder. But this strategy seems to be incorrect in case of DEVELOPMENT assemblies or tools, because this will pollute the output folder with the assemblies that are NOT required in runtime, but only at build time.

The only solution I have found is to include all the required assemblies in the package with my MSBuild task, but it has obvious drawbacks, such as huge package size.